# Way to scale all assets in a Unity3d scene

Tags: unity-game-engine

Does anyone know of a component or a way to scale multiple objects in a scene, including hierarchies of objects and objects created externally as well as internally ? It I want to be able to set an arbitrary scale amount, then scale the specified objects and colliders while keeping all the objects in the same relative place.

Answer (score 1):

Use the Scale property in the Transform component, as discussed in the Unity3D documentation:

*"[Every object in a scene has a Transform. It's used to store and manipulate the position, rotation and scale of the object. Every Transform can have a parent, which allows you to apply position, rotation and scale hierarchically.](http://docs.unity3d.com/Documentation/ScriptReference/Transform.html)"*

Answer (score 1):

Select any number of objects in the Hierarchy pane (using Ctrl or Shift for selection modifiers) and manipulate the Scale X/Y/Z in the Transform panel. That's if you wish to override the scale for everything you've selected, if you wish to scale them relative to how they currently are, use the Scaling tool (Press R over Scene view) and drag the scaling widget. You can scale all axis at the same time by dragging the scaling widget's central cube.

As child objects are influenced by their parent transform, you don't need to worry about manually selecting all children. If a child has scale .5,.5,.5 and the parent has scale .5,.5,.5, the child will appear in the scene as .25,.25,.25, for example.

Setting the size of Collider components requires a new set of selections. In the Hierarchy pane, press the magnifying glass in the search box (next to 'Create') and set it to 'Type'. Type in 'collider' and it will filter all objects that have a collider in the scene. If you select any amount of these, the collider component will show up in the Inspector pane. You can manually enter numbers in the Size fields to override the values for all, or you can use the mouse to drag each X/Y/Z box to apply relative scaling for all objects selected.

Answer (score 0):

The best solution for scaling scenes at design time would be to use the MultiAsset scaler from the Unity asset store (http://u3d.as/content/s-cps-oft/multi-asset-scaler), looks like it should cater for all your requirements.